# Mono MissingMethodException: DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds not found

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm trying to write a telegram bot using https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot,
it's a C# api for Telegram Bots.

The compiled program works on Windows without any problems, but when trying to run it using Mono on a Raspbian Linux (Debian on ARM Processor), it crashes with a

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds' not found.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable
```

plus the remainder of the whole stacktrace. The telegram.bot methods use the Newtonsoft.Json to serialize requests/deserialize responses obviously.

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.2 (Stable 4.2.2.30/996df3c Fri Jan 00:48:14 UTC 2016)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can only report the issue to Mono and wait for a fix, or report to Json.Net and see if there is a workaround.

Comment: This is a sertialization error because DateTimeOffset is lacking the function FromUnixTimeSeconds. If you know which property throws the exception you can always add a [JsonProperty] attribute to the property and create your own converter to avoid the use of the unimplemented function

Answer (score 0):

It`s coz lacks of DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds in older .Net versions coz this extention added in Net 4.6, ofc i also would going to tell it to MrRR for fixing backward compatibility about this, but might your prj .Net version is lower, also it seems you used from the methods as awaitable usage and so it would throw an exception.

BTW you can do somethings around it,

**1: Most usual**

```
        try
        {
            // your code
            var result = await bot.SendPhoto(id, file);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handleing code
        }
```

*or more as you know for more accurate:*

```
        try
        {
            // your code
            var result = await bot.SendPhoto(id, file);
        }

        //-- Because this exception is a kind of AggregateExceptions
        catch (AggregateException ex) 
        // for C# 6.0 you can use when (somehow)
        // catch (AggregateException ex) when (something to check  Method not found)
        {
            // handleing code
        }
```

**2: Yourself add an extension (i didn't checked this yet)**

try to add the extention with exact "FromUnixTimeSeconds" to the DateTimeOffset, and implement the method with the same return.
for know how you can implement it better like .Net 4.6 can use from this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds(v=vs.110).aspx

and ofc this is base exception and full stacktrace for someones can help more about this:

```
   Method not found: 'System.DateTimeOffset System.DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(Int64)'.
   at Telegram.Bot.Helpers.UnixDateTimeConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Telegram.Bot.Api.<SendWebRequest>d__106`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at [Your Project and line code]
```

hope these help you

If you need to know why this exactly happen and can put more information about it